# How to Differentiate f(x)= x[x]

Tags: derivatives

How are we supposed to differentiate problems like this( with GIF)
GIF is a non differentiable function right?
Please help me!

Comment: You are supposed to prove that this is not differentiable. At which points would you try to show that this is not differentiable? Your hint is a point where the function $[x]$ jumps.

Comment: Ik that it's 0 where the function is cont. That is between 2 integers and it's not defined in the integer values.

Comment: So x won't make any difference then?

Comment: No, I think you are misunderstanding. What is the definition of differentiability at some point, say $x$?  We have some limit definition, like $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$, and when this exists, we call the function differentiable at that point, right? So I am telling you that at the points where $[x]$ jumps, which you correctly said are the integers, this function is not differentiable. That means, you have to show that this limit which I mentioned, does not exist.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I got that, it's non differentiable at integers. I just wanted to Know if that x multiplied to it, will make any difference or not!

Comment: It would greatly improve you Question to include what you say in the above Comment directly in the body of the Question.  If you prefer, I'll edit that insight into it for you (but you should expect to include such details so that Readers have a feel for the kind of response that will help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have got that $[x]$ is not differentiable, then indeed $x[x]$ won't be differentiable either. This is simply because of the chain rule : If $x[x]$ were differentiable, then *wherever possible* (that is, on $x \neq 0$), $[x] = \left(\frac 1x\right) \circ (x[x])$ would be differentiable, but then this is not true, so we get that $x[x]$ isn't differentiable either. Alternately, you could have also showed this using the limit definition.

Comment: The argument breaks down at $x=0$.  It's not true in general that if $f$ is not differentiable at 0, then $g(x) = x f(x)$ is not differentiable at 0.  In fact, if $f$ is continuous at 0, then $g(x) = x f(x)$ *is* differentiable at 0 and $g'(0) = f(0)$.  (Which says nothing in this case since the floor function is discontinuous at 0.)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on this. All I needed to show that it was not differentiable, though.

Comment: That bit about "wherever possible" applies everywhere *but* $x=0,$ so this does *not* show that the function isn't differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @CameronBuie So to show that it is not differentiable at zero, one needs to go through the limit.

Comment: Probably so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto x[x]$ is not differentiable at integer points $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, since it has jump-discontinuities there:
$$\lim_{h\to 0+}(n+h)[n+h]=n^2$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0-}(n+h)[n+h]=n(n-1)$$
And even if it was continuous, the one-sided derivatives are not the same:
$$f'_+(n)=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{(n+h)[n+h]-n[n]}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{(n+h)n-n^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{nh}{h}=n$$

$$f'_-(n)=\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{(n+h)[n+h]-n[n]}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{(n+h)(n-1)-n(n-1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{h(n-1)}{h}=n-1.$$

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is continuous but not differentiable at $x=0$, as your graph illustrates.